# How to split long data and send it as chunks in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using php to store data into mysql using **prepared statements**, and the data I am sending is in blobs, these are just cipher text encrypted with `AES-256`, so I am storing them in a binary format so, it's not an image. I figured out in order to store blob data into mysql using php I need to use `send-long-data` from `mysqli`.

Since it's not an image, I couldn't find a single tutorial to store blob data which is not a file, and I am stuck.

I have prepared a code that splits the string into chunks, but the results seem to be incomplete and only the first chunk is stored, how do I store it correctly? I think the problem is somewhere in `str_split()`, I would be grateful if you could correct the code. And also, I copied the chunk size from [php.net](http://php.net). What should be the optimal size, in order to get the best performance, based on the fact that the cipher data maybe really big?

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO data_store (eid,  ekey, ecipher) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

//Initialise variables
$eid = $postedID;
$ekey = NULL;
$ecipher = NULL;

if($stmt->bind_param("sbb", $eid, $ekey, $ecipher)) {

    // Send blobs
    $ekey_chunks = str_split($postedKey, 8192);
    foreach ($ekey_chunks as $chunk) {
        $stmt->send_long_data(1, $chunk);
    }

    $ecipher_chunks = str_split($postedCipher, 8192);
    foreach ($ecipher_chunks as $chunk) {
        $stmt->send_long_data(2, $chunk);
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}

$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Since it's not an image, I couldn't find a single tutorial to store blob data which is not a file, and I am stuck.

An image is a binary data all the same. So you can use any tutorial.

To fix your code just get rid of that chunking stuff and run your query usual way.

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssb", $eid, $ekey, $ecipher);
$stmt->execute();
```

**IS ALL THE CODE YOU NEED**

Comment: Then why does php recommend chunking the data before sending it to mysql?

Comment: That's really not helping, there must be something about maximum packet size allowed and stuff like that.

Comment: Whatever. Your only problem was a peculiar idea that an image is not a file, which is now resolved. You may proceed with any tutorial you mentioned above.

Comment: I did not say an image is not a file, I said- "Since it's not an image, I couldn't find a single tutorial to store **blob data** which is **not a file**...", the blob data output is stored in a variable before being stored in php.